# How to read a variable inside a powershell command written in a .bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have this bat file that i execute and it works great:

```
SET RPPROPERTIESPATH='C:\work\filepath.txt' //contains the word 'string1'

powershell -Command "(gc %RPPROPERTIESPATH%) -replace 'string1', 'string2' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %RPPROPERTIESPATH%"
```

But i want the replace param to come from a variable like so:

```
SET RPPROPERTIESPATH='C:\work\filepath.txt' //contains the word 'string1'
SET STRINGTOREPLACE='string3' 

 powershell -Command "(gc %RPPROPERTIESPATH%) -replace 'string1', %STRINGTOREPLACE% | Out-File -encoding ASCII %RPPROPERTIESPATH%"
```

This is not working, how should i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work once i exclude the ' like so:

```
SET STRINGTOREPLACE=string3

 powershell -Command "(gc %RPPROPERTIESPATH%) -replace 'string1', '%STRINGTOREPLACE%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %RPPROPERTIESPATH%"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Set variables](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) using `set "varname=varvalue"` syntax pattern and *use them quoted if necessary* like `"%varname%"` (for *cmd*) or like `'%varname%'` (for *PowerShell*). Then, your code snippet should be as follows:

```
SET "RPPROPERTIESPATH=C:\work\filepath.txt" //contains the word 'string1'
SET "STRINGTOREPLACE=string3"

powershell -Command "(gc '%RPPROPERTIESPATH%') -replace 'string1', '%STRINGTOREPLACE%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII '%RPPROPERTIESPATH%'"
```